# How to update kwargs the Ruby / Rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, keyword-argument

I have this in a GraphQL resolver:

```
def resolve(id:, tag_ids: nil, **kwargs)
  article = current_user.articles.find(id)
  tags = tag_ids ? Tag.where(id: tag_ids) : article.tags
  article.update!(tags: tags, **kwargs)
  article
end
```

I basically want to only pass in the `tags` key/value pair to `article.update!` if tags is NOT `nil`. I am doing an ugly hack by setting it back to `article.tags`.

How do I do this the proper way, can I do something like this?

```
def resolve(id:, tag_ids: nil, **kwargs)
  article = current_user.articles.find(id)
  tags = tag_ids ? Tag.where(id: tag_ids) : nil
  if tags then kwargs.append!(tags: tags)
  article.update!(**kwargs)
  article
end
```

If there's no standard way of doing this, what is a better way to accomplish this so it's less messy and works?

Comment: Whats the goal here? Should `tag_ids` be added to the exisiting tags or replace anything previously exisiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BEWARE** The suggested code is destructive and removes tags that are not being passed in. If (instead) you want the tags to be additive, see update #2.

If that's the case, you're very close. `kwargs` is just a plain hash, so I'd do something like the following:

```rb
def resolve(id:, tag_ids: nil, **kwargs)
  article = current_user.articles.find(id)
  kwargs[:tags] = Tag.where(id: tag_ids) if tag_ids
  article.update!(**kwargs)
  article
end
```

A pattern that I like for operating on and then returning a certain object is `tap`. It can be confusing to those newer to ruby / less familiar with the pattern, however, so YYMV.

```rb
def resolve(id:, tag_ids: nil, **kwargs)
  current_user.articles.find(id).tap do |article|
    kwargs[:tags] = Tag.where(id: tag_ids) if tag_ids
    article.update!(**kwargs)
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Depending on how your model associations are setup you may be able to skip the lookup entirely. For example, if the Article class `has_many :tags`, then ActiveRecord provides a `tag_ids=` method for you.

In which case you could do:

```
def resolve(id:, tag_ids: nil, **kwargs)
  article = current_user.articles.find(id)
  kwargs[:tag_ids] = tag_ids if tag_ids
  article.update!(**kwargs)
  article
end
```

**UPDATE #2**

If you want to add the tags that are passed in to the existing array, you'll want to do that explicitly, e.g.:

```
def resolve(id:, tag_ids: nil, **kwargs)
  article = current_user.articles.find(id)
  kwargs[:tag_ids] = article.tag_ids + tag_ids if tag_ids
  article.update!(**kwargs)
  article
end
```

Comment: One thing to beware of with the `_ids` setter is that it will destroy exisiting records if they are not in the array. If you want the process to be purely additive your want `articles.tags.ids || (tag_ids || [])`.

Comment: great point - will try to disambiguate, not clear what he was asking